# How to disable a DIV on Checkbox Click by using JS?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript and I have tried this code but it's not working. Here `UPDOC` is the `div` id:

```
function ChangeText() {
    var chkb = document.getElementById('<%= CHKDOC.ClientID %>');
    if (chkb.checked)
        document.getElementById('<%= UPDOC.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
    else
        document.getElementById('<%= UPDOC.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? Code not working, doesn't help

Comment: What does "disable a div" mean? "Disable" is something you do to form fields, not divs.

Comment: error: null reference

Comment: Is that ERB / haml syntax? What's it doing there? In any case it sounds like `getElementById` is returning `null` and you are trying to access properties of `null`. Try logging what `chkb` is before the if statement.

Comment: disable=readonly(greyish)

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#UPDOC{
border:2px solid red;
height:140px;
width:400px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.ee{
pointer-events:none;
user-select:none;
}
</style>
<script>
function ChangeText() {
    var chkb = document.getElementById('chkbox');
    if (chkb.checked)
        document.getElementById('UPDOC').className="ee";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" onclick="ChangeText()"/>
<div id="UPDOC">
<p>hello</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not only wanting to disable the div but also do the same to its childrend, please check my solution. Hope it help

```js
function ChangeText(chkb) {
 var div = document.getElementById('div');
 div.disabled = chkb.checked;
 var chl = div.children;
 for(var i=0; i< chl.length; i++)
 {
  chl[i].disabled = chkb.checked;
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" onclick=ChangeText(this)>
<div id="div" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;" >
<input type="text" value="123" />
</div>
```

Comment: how to enable the div when checkbox is Checked ?

Comment: you use this line: div.disabled = !chkb.checked;

Comment: it's working here(disable functionality) because u are using input but if u use ASP control it will not work !!